# How to paste a line in a vertical selection block?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-mode

Consider the following text:

```
long foobar=(test);
int  barbar=(something);
char foofoo=();
```

Suppose I have yanked some chunk of code which I want to place before each opening parenthesis, e.g. `funcName`. What I currently have to do is just manually enter the addition after selecting e.g. all the `(` via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>, and then after pressing <kbd>I</kbd>, enter `funcName` (thus disregarding contents of yank register).

Is there a way to instead *insert* the text before selection, like I'd do using <kbd>P</kbd> for a single line?

Comment: Related: [How to paste before the cursor after selecting a vertical block?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4073731/55075) at SO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In insert mode, you can use `<C-r>"` to insert the content of the unnamed register (replace `"` with `b` if what you want to insert is stored in register `b`):

```
<C-v>jjI<C-r>"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the "normal" command so that it would work even if the `(` are not aligned.

`Vjj` To select the three lines

`:normal f(P` To execute `f(` (find first `(`) and `P` to paste on all three lines.

This makes it also easier to repeat (by selecting other lines, hitting `:` and <kbd>Up</kbd>